# Cordova build error code 1

Tags: android, linux, cordova, phonegap-cli

I am trying to build android project by cordova but I still always having error . here is the terminal output:

```
tobe@tobe-laptop:~/DemoProject$ cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=/home/tobe/android-sdk-linux
JAVA_HOME=/home/tobe/java/jdk1.8.0_91
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources FAILED
```

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
>
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/tobe/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 127
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
>   BUILD FAILED
>
>   Total time: 3.544 secs
>     Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/tobe/DemoProject/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/tobe/DemoProject/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true

Comment: Is your system is 64 bit ? and `'/home/tobe/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt` command in terminal.

Comment: My system is 64 bit . how should this be in terminal?

Comment: Because by the above command will not work. It requires the 32 bit library packages for execute. Install these packages `lib32z1` and `ia32-libs`. The same issue I had faced when I built.

Comment: i've installed them already

Comment: getting same issue .. any fix ?